# Looking for a recent fan funded movie

Tags: story-identification

There is a recent fan funded movie (I believe) with a main character phoenix in it. It is set in a futuristic London, where there is tower they called the Pod in the city. Phoenix operated a "Pacific Rim" type robot.
It was on Youtube however account of the subscriber was deleted, does anyone know the name of the movie?

Comment: What was the youtube account name?